# How do I get "foreign"/special characters to print properly in data from YouTube Data API?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have the following code which I am using to get the first comment on a video:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String apiKey = "[redacted]";
        
    YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        }
    }).setApplicationName("youtube-view-count-test").build();
        
    System.out.println(getFirstComment(youtube,"-BAvLYgq5m0", apiKey));
}

public static String getFirstComment(YouTube youtube, String videoId, String apiKey) throws IOException
{
    String commentText, author, date;
    YouTube.CommentThreads.List list2 = youtube.commentThreads().list(Arrays.asList("snippet"));
    list2.setVideoId(videoId);
    list2.setKey(apiKey);
    List<CommentThread> c = list2.execute().getItems();
    Comment c2 = c.get(0).getSnippet().getTopLevelComment();
        
    return getFormattedCommentString(c2);
}
```

But there's a problem: the comment (and apparently the username) are Japanese I think, and when I print to `System.out` all I get is a bunch of question marks. `getFormattedCommentString` simply puts the comment info (username, text, date) in one `String` to print out and doesn't do anything strange; I tested before calling this method and the comment text was already "corrupted". So, does anyone know what I need to do to retrieve the actual text of a comment in cases where the text is not simply ASCII or whatever charset is being used?

Comment: The console on which you print the text does not support UTF-8 output.  If using `cmd.exe` on Windows, switch to code page 65001.  If your output is in an IDE, configure the IDE console to UTF-8.  You may also need to have non-Latin fonts installed.  There are too many variables in all this, depending on your OS and software settings, to give a one-size-fits-all answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, turns out the problem was in my IDE, Eclipse...set the workspace encoding to UTF-8 and it works like a charm.